# Selenium - Unable to find password field element based on CSS element on [a link] http://www.cartasi.it/gtwpages/index.jsp

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to find password field element from a link  http://www.cartasi.it/gtwpages/index.jsp using CSS selectors. Following is the code I used for other websites, it is working fine for all websites except the provided link.

```
 pwd=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='password']"))
```

and checked the source code of the website but i did not find any type="password" keyword in the code. 
i feel like posting source code of entire website would create chaos hence gave the link to refer. 
What could be causing this password hidden? How can I locate the element using CSS selector? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I opened the page, and was not able to see any sort of login form. Are you sure there is a password field on that page?

Comment: you can find username and password at top right of the page.

Comment: Source code of the website is not displaying any input fields . Is there any reason for hiding the code for those elements? if so how is it possible and how can firebug get the entire source code of website including all the input fields. Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I was able to get a reference to it in the browser console using ```document.querySelector("input[type='password']")```. Not sure about Selenium though.

Comment: Thanks for your response and time but i am into selenium working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password field on that page is inside the `iframe`:

```
<iframe width="254" height="120" frameborder="0" src="https://titolari.cartasi.it/portal/login/login.xhtml" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no">
...
<input id="loginForm:password" class="ui-inputfield ui-password ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="password" tabindex="2" placeholder="" name="loginForm:password" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
```

So you need to switch to iframe first and then use your selector:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // make sure you are on main page
driver.switchTo().frame(
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'login.xhtml')]")));
pwd=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='password']"))
```

Of course you can change the xpath / selection method to whatever you prefer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helped me to understand the difference between source code and inspect element code in browser.